# string.find function returning odd numbers

Tags: c++, string

I am trying to find the position at which a character was found.

```
const char* normalize(std::string path) 
{
    std::cout << "executed   " << path << std::endl;
    //"foo//\\\bar////bar2///../.\bar2" -- foo/bar/bar2
    std::size_t found;
    std::size_t found2;
    std::size_t curchar = 0;
    std::string final;
    std::string buffer;
    bool notdone = true;

    while (notdone) {
        //std::cout << "loop" << std::endl;
        //find the current element
        // can be / or \
        found = path.find("/", curchar);
        found2 = path.find("\\",curchar);
        std::cout << found << std::endl;
        SDL_Delay(2000);
        if (found != std::string::npos && found2 != std::string::npos) {
            if (found < found2){
                //read from the curchar to the slash
                if (curchar-found > 1){
                    buffer = path.substr(curchar,found-curchar-1);
                    //add to path
                    final = final + "/" + buffer;
                }
                curchar = found+1;
                //buffer will be the file/component
            }else{
                if (curchar-found2 > 1){
                    buffer = path.substr(curchar,found2-curchar-1);
                    //add to path
                    final = final + "/" + buffer;
                }
                curchar = found2+1;
            }
        }else if(found != std::string::npos){
            //std::cout << "loop2" << found == std::string::npos << std::endl;
            //std::cout << "loop2   " << path.substr(curchar, 1) << std::endl;
            if (curchar-found > 1){//
                buffer = path.substr(curchar,found-curchar-1);
                //add to path
                final = final + "/" + buffer;
            }
            curchar = found+1;
        }else if(found2 != std::string::npos){
            std::cout << "loop3" << std::endl;
            if (curchar-found2 > 1){
                buffer = path.substr(curchar,found2-curchar-1);
                //add to path
                final = final + "/" + buffer;
            }
            curchar = found2+1;
        }else{
            std::cout << "finishing" << std::endl;
            final = final + "/" + path.substr(curchar,path.size()-curchar);
            notdone = false;
        }
    }

    return final.c_str();
}

normalize("test/");
```

This code should print out '4', but it instead prints out 18. It prints out 18 in an infinite loop. However, if I use `std::cout << path.find("/", curchar) << std::endl` it does print 4. At first I thought that it wasn't actually returning `std::size_t` but I checked and it was.

Comment: I have changed the code

Comment: Make it runnable, then one can talk.

Comment: [Even so, it still works as you say it should](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/26298da39c1f762c).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your following line is creating the problem

```
  //find the current element
  // can be / or \
  found = path.find("/", curchar);
```

I ran on my linux terminal and GCC treated as next line as continuation of comment of above line.

```
basic.cpp:18:9: warning: multi-line comment [-Wcomment]
         // can be / or \
         ^
basic.cpp: In function ‘const char* normalize(std::string)’:
basic.cpp:21:22: warning: ‘found’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
         std::cout << found << std::endl;
                      ^
```

Now due to above comment style, your next line(code) was treated as comment. As *found* was not initialized so it had garbage value which screwed up your logic as it did not go inside the path where you have reset the flag *notdone*.

However GCC or any other compiler should give warning(usage of uninitialize variable) and if we would have carefully read, we might have back-trace and  understood the problem.

Solution for this would be to change the comment style as

```
/* // can be / or \ */
```